# Round decimals to upper value using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple `SUM` with `ROUND` statements as:

```
SUM(ROUND([SOI].[SOIQuantity] * [SOI].[SOIPrice], 2)) AS [TotalPrice]
```

The result of this is: `4747.65`

The funny thing is, if I use three decimals, the result is: `4747.662`

So my question is: why is it round the decimals to .65 instead .66? My desired result is to get .66, how can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: You've misdiagnosed the issue. You're restricting the accuracy of the INPUTS to the sum. Apply the rounding AFTER the SUM and the results will be consistent. `1.111 + 1.111 + 1.111 + 1.111 + 1.111 == 5.555`. When you round it AFTER the SUM you'd get 5.56, but if you round the inputs you'd get `1.11 + 1.11 + 1.11 + 1.11 + 1.11 = 5.55`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ROUND(SUM([SOI].[SOIQuantity] * [SOI].[SOIPrice]), 2) AS [TotalPrice]
```

Comment: This answer lacks any explanation as to WHY, which is specifically asked in the op.

Comment: It works, but why?

Comment: @jesus `1.111 + 1.111 + 1.111 + 1.111 + 1.111 == 5.555`. When you round it AFTER the SUM you'd get 5.56

Comment: @jesus If you round before the SUM, however; `1.11 + 1.11 + 1.11 + 1.11 + 1.11 == 5.55`

Comment: do the calculate and preserve decimal points before rounding the values, this gives a more accurate answer